# What is this 4 pin header on the Creality 4.2.3 board?

Tags: creality, part-identification

What might these 4 pins be on the Creality 4.2.3 board be?

The silkscreen says

```
G
SC
SD
V
```

[image: Photo of Creality 4.2.3 board with 4-pin header circled]

It is next to the pin header for the LCD, so I suspect it is either a UART or TFT port.

Googling I suspect `SD` *might* be short for SDA and `SC` *might* be short for `SCL`. Which are common I2C pin descriptions.

https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/pull/23307#issuecomment-996371949

Answer (score 2):

I found [the unofficial schematics](https://github.com/Creality3DPrinting/Ender-3/issues/58#issuecomment-982732560) for the very similar 4.2.2 Creality board.

It contains a 4 pin header titled ICSP port.
Note that these appear to be 3.3 V pins

[image: Portion of a schematic for the Creality 4.2.3 board showing the ICSP port]